# How do I hide the tag-container when there's no tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, tags, hide

I was wondering how I could get #tag-container to only display when there's tags. How do I do this? I'm thinking there's some if and else statements, but I can't figure out how to correctly write it...

```
<div class="tag-container">
    <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
if( get_the_tags() ){
    echo '<div class="tag-container"><p>';
    the_tags();
    echo '</p></div>';
}
```

Comment: Great, this worked perfectly :) Could this be done using the get_the_excerpt as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (!empty(get_the_tags())) : ?>
<div class="tag-container">
    <p><?php the_tags(); ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers I would store the rendered tags in a variable to not call the same function twice.

```
<?php $tags = get_the_tag_list( __('Tags: '), ', ' ); ?>
<?php if( !empty( $tags ) ) : ?>
<div class="tag-container">
    <p><?php echo $tags; ?></p>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The tags would need to be imploded and linked if he needs them to display properly, this will simply show `Array` as the value :) something like `'<a href="...">'.implode('</a>, <a href="...">', $tags) . '</a>'`

Comment: Does it matter that the tags are already called by get_the_tags? :)

Comment: @michaelw90 This is a speed-optimizing strategy; [at]ChenAsraf Sorry, didn't saw that – thanks for your hint. (But there are many other Wordpress methods that work after that schema)